# how do I return the variable and then update the label in python/tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
def ChangeDialog(d):
    global labeltext
    d = filedialog.askdirectory()
    labeltextVar.set(f"{d1}-->{d2}")
    return d
    
labeltextVar = StringVar()
labeltextVar.set(f"{d1}-->{d2}")
labeltext = tk.Label(textvariable=labeltextVar).pack()
atext = ttk.Button(text="CHANGE PATH A", command=lambda: ChangeDialog(d1))
btext = ttk.Button(text="CHANGE PATH B", command=lambda: ChangeDialog(d2))
```

How do I get this so that once d is set in the ChangeDialog Function, it returns it THEN updates the label(In this case labeltext)?

I tried without the return statement, using a text variable instead of text, and more.

Comment: def ChangeDialog(d):
        global labeltext
        d = filedialog.askdirectory()
        labeltextVar.set(f"{d1}-->{d2}")
        return d
        
    labeltextVar = StringVar()
    labeltextVar.set(f"{d1}-->{d2}")
    labeltext = tk.Label(textvariable=labeltextVar).pack()
    atext = ttk.Button(text="CHANGE PATH A", command=lambda: ChangeDialog(d1))
    btext = ttk.Button(text="CHANGE PATH B", command=lambda: ChangeDialog(d2))

Comment: Please format and indent your code properly.

Comment: It is utterly pointless to return anything from a Button's `command=` function.  You're not the one calling that function, and Tkinter is not going to do anything with the returned value.

Comment: update `Label` directly in `ChangeDialog`

Comment: if you have new code then put it in question, not in comments. It will be more readable, and more people may see it - so more people can help you.

Comment: BTW: mistake in `labeltext = tk.Label(textvariable=labeltextVar).pack()` - it assign `None` to `labeltext` because `pack()`/`grid()`/`place()` returns `None`. If you need variable `labeltext` then you have to do it in two steps: `labeltext = tk.Label(textvariable=labeltextVar)` and `labeltext.pack()`

Answer (score 0):

Change `d1` and `d2` to `tk.StringVar`, then you can update it inside `ChangeDialog()` directly:

```py
...
d1 = tk.StringVar(value="/path/to/a")
d2 = tk.StringVar(value="/path/to/b")

def ChangeDialog(d):
    folder = filedialog.askdirectory()
    if folder:
        d.set(folder) # update passed StringVar
        labeltextVar.set(f"{d1.get()}-->{d2.get()}") # update label

labeltextVar = tk.StringVar()
labeltextVar.set(f"{d1.get()}-->{d2.get()}")
...
```

Answer (score 0):

**This code is worked on my pc** and Discover the functionality of this Python/Tkinter code excerpt designed to dynamically refresh a GUI label with chosen directory paths. The script introduces buttons for seamlessly switching between paths A and B, leveraging the filedialog module. Elevate the user experience of your Tkinter application by incorporating this straightforward and efficient directory selection feature.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk, filedialog

def ChangeDialog(label_var, d_var, label_text):
    d = filedialog.askdirectory()
    label_var.set(f"{label_text} --> {d}")
    d_var.set(d)

root = tk.Tk()

d1 = "Path A"
d2 = "Path B"

labeltextVar = tk.StringVar()
labeltextVar.set(f"{d1} --> {d2}")

labeltext = tk.Label(root, textvariable=labeltextVar)
labeltext.pack()

d1_var = tk.StringVar()
d2_var = tk.StringVar()

d1_var.set(d1)
d2_var.set(d2)

atext = ttk.Button(root, text="CHANGE PATH A", command=lambda: ChangeDialog(labeltextVar, d1_var, "Path A"))
btext = ttk.Button(root, text="CHANGE PATH B", command=lambda: ChangeDialog(labeltextVar, d2_var, "Path B"))

atext.pack()
btext.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I will try to integgrate this soon.